# Toplevel inside another Toplevel in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, toplevel

I was wondering if it is possible to place a toplevel inside another toplevel in tkinter. Normally you can move anywhere a toplevel, but I would like to have it contained *inside* the parent toplevel, so that it can be moved only inside it, and if one clicks anywhere else inside the parent toplevel, the child toplevel is still visible (even if not "selected"). Of course, if one moves the container toplevel, the child toplevel inside should keep the relative position to the parent. So for example, how could the "self.k" toplevel be contained inside "app" in this code:

```
import Tkinter as tk

class Main:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master=master
        self.k=tk.Toplevel(self.master)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = Main(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: Are you sure you need a `Toplevel` widget? Possible [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) here.

Comment: Thanks for ansering. What I want is a main window with different windows inside, each containing different things. Something like this picture: http://dist.alternativeto.net/s/b80a7d76-3293-45f2-84dc-07ae136df1c6_2_full.png?format=jpg&width=1900

Comment: Briefly: you'll have to hack something together if you want that.

Comment: ok, thanks. I couldn't find anything after looking for some time